# How to return hibernate entity with one extra field from another table?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I have two tables: Teacher and Student. Both of these tables have a bunch of columns; I’m only showing the relevant ones. Teachers can have multiple students, but students can only have one teacher.

Table Teacher

| id | Name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Johnson |
| 2 | Jackson |

Table Student

| id | name | teacher id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Annie | 1 |

I have a Spring Boot API that returns the student entity with the given ID. I need to update this API so that it returns the student entity along with the name of teacher. Something like this:

```
{
  
    "id": "1",
    "name": "Annie",
    "teacherId": 1,
    "teacherName": "Johnson"

}
```

I tried creating a new model call StudentModel that looks like this:

```
public class StudentModel{
    private Student student;
    private String teacherName;
}
```

The response that gets generated looks like this:

```
 {
  "student": {
     "id": "1",
    "name": "b",
    "status": "d",
    "teacherId": 1
  },
  "teacherName": "Johnson"
}
```

Is there a way to get the JSON the API returns look like this instead:

```
{
  
    "id": "1",
    "name": "Annie",
    "teacherId": 1,
    "teacherName": "Johnson"

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using Jackson, you need to add [@JsonUnwrapped](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.8/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonUnwrapped.html) annotation to the `student` field